# Checking if registry key exists with python

Tags: python, python-2.7, registry, pywin32, registrykey

I'm looking for a way to check if a registry key exists with python.

How can I do this or what code do I need to check if a registry key exists or not?

Comment: It appears there is an answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5227427/3482069).

Comment: @edwin-s this cheack registry key exists or registry exists??

Comment: I'll provide more details in an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There appears to be some information in a previous answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5227427/3482069).

Are you checking for its existence because you want your program to read it? To check for the existence of they key, you can wrap it in a `try-except` block. This will prevent "race conditions" trying to read the key, in the (unlikely) event it is modified between checking for its existence and actually reading the key. Something like:

```
from _winreg import *

key_to_read = r'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall'

try:
    reg = ConnectRegistry(None, HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE)
    k = OpenKey(reg, key_to_read)

    # do things with the key here ...

except:
    # do things to handle the exception here
```

Comment: not work, and you forget
reg = ConnectRegistry(None, HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE)
must be
aReg = ConnectRegistry(None, HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE)

Answer (score 2):

This is an older post but I felt after some similar searching, thought I would add some information to this.  `winreg` , from what I heave found, only works on a Windows Environment. [python-registry](https://github.com/williballenthin/python-registry) by **williballenthin** can be used to do this cross-platform and has a multitude of great options when working with the Registry.

If you have a target key that has values you want to pull out, you can list them out following these steps....First, import modules (pip install python-registry). This may not work as the master folder gets inserted into the libs/sitepackages, make sure the **Registry** folder is at the root of the site-packages.

```
from Registry import Registry         # Ensure Registry is in your libs/site-packages
```

Next create your function and make sure you add in a `try:` and `except`into your function to check if its there.

```
# Store internal Registry paths as variable, may make it easier, remove repeating yourself
time_zone = "ControlSet001\\Control\\TimeZoneInformation"

# STORE the path to your files if you plan on repeating this process.
<Path_To_reg_hive> = "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Whatever_Folder\\SYSTEM"

def get_data():
    registry = Registry.Registry(<Path_To_reg_hive>)  # Explicitly, or use variable above
    try:
        key = registry.open(time_zone)  # Registry.Registry opens reg file, goes to the path (time_zone)
    except Registry.RegistryKeyNotFoundException:  # This error occurs if Path is not present
        print("Sorry Bud, no key values found at : " + time_zone)  # If not there, print a response
```

You can make a dict of everything you want to check and just iterate through it with this process to check several at once, or just one at a time. Here is a working example:

```
from Registry import Registry

# These can be included directly into the function, or separated if you have several
system = "SYSTEM"   # or a Path, I have a SYSTEM hive file in my working environment folder
time_zone = "ControlSet001\\Control\\TimeZoneInformation123" # Path you want to check, added 123 so its not there

def get_data():
    registry = Registry.Registry(system)   # Explicitly, or use variable above
    try:
        key = registry.open(time_zone)       # Registry.Registry opens reg file, goes to the path (time_zone)
    except Registry.RegistryKeyNotFoundException:  # This error occurs if Path is not present
        print("Sorry Bud, no key values found at : " + time_zone)  # If not there, print a response

# key is identified above only to use later, such as....   for v in key.subkeys():    Do more stuff
get_data()
```

Which returns,

```
Sorry Bud, no key values found at : ControlSet001\Control\TimeZoneInformation123
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK you can only use a try/except combo, at least in [`winregistry`](https://pypi.org/project/winregistry/).

For instance:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3.9

import winreg as reg

key_path = "Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Explorer\\Taskband\\NumThumbnails"
try:
    key = reg.OpenKey(reg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, key_path)
    return reg.QueryValue(key, "")
except FileNotFoundError:
    print("Key does not exist")
```

You could for instance create wrappers for the different registries:

```py
def get_user_registry_key(key_path) -> Optional[reg.HKEYType]:
    try:
        return reg.OpenKey(reg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, key_path)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return None

if key := get_user_registry_key(key_path):
        print(reg.QueryValue(key, ""))
```