# Python Read Registry - QueryValueEx value_name options

Tags: python, win32com, winreg

I'm trying to collect a list of available *value_name*s to query with `QueryValueEx`as in this post: [Python code to read registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5227107/python-code-to-read-registry?lq=1)

The *value_name* string options I've seen are *DisplayName* (which works), *Description, InstallRoot, DeviceID, DeviceGUID* (all of which do not work for me). I tested each by simply substituting the *value_name* option in the following line:

```
val = QueryValEx(asubkey, value_name)
```

Does anyone know how to get a list of the available options that works with the above code?

On an additional note, what I am trying to retrieve is the appropriate string for dispatching Autodesk Design Review via `win32com.client`. I believe, but don't know, that I can find this string by querying the registry value.

Comment: Did you make sure the subkey actually has those values in it (e.g. via regedit)? Also, what do you mean by "do not work" - are you getting some sort of error?

Comment: Unfortunately regedit has been disabled on my network, so I cannot view it. And by "do not work", I simply mean looping through keys and querying them against those value_names yield no results. The only one that yields anything thus far is 'DisplayName'