# Reading windows registry using python

Tags: windows, python-2.7, registry

I am beginner and started learning python myself since it helps in doing automation. I would like to know how to read a value i.e. dword , binary or SZ from windows registry using python. I have requirement where a value needs to be read and then compare that value with a specified value and produce the result lets say "compliant" or "non-compliant"

I went through different forums and it is not easily understandable. I will appreciate if anyone can help me out reading a value and printing it.

Also, a book for learning python if someone can recommend.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python code to read registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5227107/python-code-to-read-registry)

Answer (score 1):

You can use python's [Windows registry access](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/winreg.html) for accessing windows registry.
You can also refer [python code to read reqistory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5227107/python-code-to-read-registry).

Hope this helps you.